# Get S3 presigned url for media in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

we am using django rest framework for a project and here we are trying to avoid using serializers. We have our AWS S3 as private , hence we need to provide a presigned key for the user to be able to see the image . Initially , we had our S3 as public so we were using annotate function to convert the image path to image link like this :

```py
def getImageFormatter(key: str) -> Func:
    """Function to Get Formatted URL"""
    return Case(
        When(
            **{f'{key}__exact':''},
            then=Value(None)
            ),
        When(
            **{f'{key}__isnull':False},
            then=Concat(
                Value(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
                F(key),output_field=CharField()
            )
        ),
        default=Value(None),
        output_field=CharField(null=True)
    )
```

The problem is , this only works for public S3 . For private how can we do so so that we can get image on annotate? like using a custom django db function or something else? Any leads will be appreciated .

The database we are using is `PostgreSQL`.
We are using `boto3` and `django-storages` to connect to our s3 bucket.

We are actually not trying to run it through a serializer , and we are getting the data directly by using annotate and values.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193171/how-to-generate-presigned-s3-urls-using-django-storages

Comment: @jarmod hi , the question does talk about generating urls , but my issue is to generate it in such a way so that i can get the final url in the queryset.values() result .

Comment: @unownone I think one way you can achieve this is by implementing a simple custom field that will do the thing. You just need to be aware that EVERY record will cause an extra call to S3 api in order to receive a presigned url. Another thing you can consider is just  introduce property on the model that will get the presigned url. Let me know if it helps or you want any clarification.